# currently i work for this equation but seems couldnt find a solution , i wrote it this way

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

[image: equation 2]

```
$x^\lambda_p$ + $x^\lambda_p$ \leq $y_\lambda$ \forall \in \wedge, \forall ($p$,$p$) \in $P^2$
```

Comment: You should definitely look at a beginner's guide.

Comment: You appear to lack, at present, a basic understanding of how and why to switch between TeX's text and math modes. To get a grip on this topic, and to also familiarize yourself with other LaTeX fundamentals, you might consult [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) by Tobias Oetiker et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with egreg's and Mico's comments: please take a look at a beginner's guide. In particular, read up on TeX's modes --- specifically math mode.

That said, to answer your immediate question,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
x^\lambda_p + x^\lambda_{p'} \le y^\lambda \quad \forall \lambda \in \Lambda, \quad \forall (p, p') \in P^2
\]
\end{document}
```

will produce the formula in your picture.

Comment: thanks a lot i will but its just urgent work

Comment: @QussayA.Ameer A new software (like LaTeX) is not something to start learning when you need to accomplish urgent work.

Comment: And reading and understanding https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10 for example is less time than asking, following, and waiting for answer here....