# Equation structure is hard, i wrote it this way below

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image: Report image for solve]

```
$Y$ \leq $Y$\lambda$k$+1.  \forall $K$ \in \|1, \wedge-1
```

Comment: Please write your posts so they have a question, and provide examples as a complete small document that people  can test. But you should delete all the `$` the entire expression should be in a single math formula say between `\[` and `\]`

Comment: I humbly suggest you to look at https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10 (and possibly the rest of that site). It is time we'll invested!

Comment: Another good intro to writing mathematical expressions in LaTeX is Chapter 3, "Typesetting mathematical formulae" [sic] of [The not so short introduction to LaTeX2e](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) by Tobias Oetiker and others.

Comment: Don't use `\wedge`; use `\Lambda` instead.

Comment: This is suspiciously similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590376/107497

Comment: Thanks ill do it

Answer (score 0):

For the double brackets you can use `stmaryrd`, the rest is pretty much straight forward.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}
\[
  y_{\lambda_{k}} \geq y_{\lambda_{k+1}} \quad
  \forall k\in\llbracket1,\lvert\Lambda\rvert-1\rrbracket
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works ill take your advice